# Create PDF file from Raw PDF Content

Tags: php, pdf

I am getting raw PDF data from an API and want to create PDF file from this data.

The raw PDF data looks like:

%PDF-1.5
%

....................

....................

%%EOF

I created PDF file with above content with the help of PHP file handling functions and it seems file is created successfully. However when newly created PDF is opened, it simply shows blank white page (without any content). If same file is opened in IDE (like notepad++), it shows the raw content written in correctly.

I even tried PHP header with different params with no luck. I also tried using DOMPDF library and that still doesn't help either.

I guess there is some extra information in raw content (maybe header, filename etc.) and I need to get actual content from it but I have no idea how?

Can anyone guide me what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a different PDF reader?

Comment: Yes, I did. I open it in Adobe PDF reader, PDF Reader for Windows and in different browsers. All of them open it but I can see blank white page only.

Comment: A file is just a sequence of bytes, so if you're saving the bytes transmitted to you accurately, that's the file you've been sent. Maybe the API is corrupting or escaping the data in some way?

Comment: FYI, I also tried it with xlsx (API returns both pdf and xlsx versions) and it also has exactly same issue.

Comment: Make sure that you are saving out the stream as a binary file and not as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

**try following script i think you miss some header:**

```
$path = /path/to/yourfilename.pdf;

$content = <your raw pdf data>;

//put your content to file
file_put_contents($path, $content);

header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');

// force download
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
header('Content-Type: application/download', false);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);

readfile($path);

exit();
```